# What's the best way currently to get events to a Go app that uses go-ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, events, golang

I have generated and used [Go bindings](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Native-DApps:-Go-bindings-to-Ethereum-contracts) to deploy a few contracts and that worked very well, but I see events are not implemented yet. Is this work discussed somewhere?

**I'd like to understand what options there are for a server-side app in Go to watch events on deployed smart contracts?**

I know events are wrappers around EVM log ops and reside as entries inside transaction receipts. Also, watching events are done per contract instance (not by class).

I would like to avoid manually parsing out events which I could do using either [polling JSON RPC log changes](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getfilterchanges) or [RPC pub/sub for logs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/RPC-PUB-SUB#logs).

What is the currently suggested way in Go? Please show with an example in code. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

[Opened an issue for go-ethereum to add events for Go bindings](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2792) so please +1. :)

Comment: did you found a way how to do it? I also have the same need.

Answer (score 1):

Until the `abigen` will generate code to access events through the contract interface you should use [Client.SubscribeFilterLogs](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient#Client.SubscribeFilterLogs) method. It's pretty self-explained. You have to provide a channel which will be fed by logs. Also, don't forget to listen on `Subscription.Err()`.

Check consensys article: [Technical Introduction to Events and Logs in Ethereum](https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e) for information about handling Logs in Ethereum.

Example:

```
query := ethereum.FilterQuery{
    FromBlock: nil,
    ToBlock:   nil,
    // Topics [][]common.Hash
    Addresses: []common.Address{myContractAddress}}
var logs = make(chan types.Log, 2)
s, err := client.SubscribeFilterLogs(context.TODO(), query, logs)
// check err
errChan := s.Err()
for {
    select {
    case err := <-errChan:
        logger.Error("Logs subscription error", err)
        break
    case l := <-logs:
        logger.Info("new log", log15.Spew(l))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "github.com/miguelmota/go-web3-example/greeter"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    greeterAddress := "a7b2eb1b9fff7c9625373a6a6d180e36b552fc4c"
    priv := "abcdbcf6bdc3a8e57f311a2b4f513c25b20e3ad4606486d7a927d8074872cefg"

    key, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(priv)

    contractAddress := common.HexToAddress(greeterAddress)
    greeterClient, err := greeter.NewGreeter(contractAddress, client)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    auth := bind.NewKeyedTransactor(key)

    // not sure why I have to set this when using testrpc
    // var nonce int64 = 0
    // auth.Nonce = big.NewInt(nonce)

    tx, err := greeterClient.Greet(auth, "hello")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Pending TX: 0x%x\n", tx.Hash())

    query := ethereum.FilterQuery{
        Addresses: []common.Address{contractAddress},
    }

    var ch = make(chan types.Log)
    ctx := context.Background()

    sub, err := client.SubscribeFilterLogs(ctx, query, ch)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Subscribe:", err)
        return
    }

    for {
        select {
        case err := <-sub.Err():
            log.Fatal(err)
        case log := <-ch:
            fmt.Println("Log:", log)
        }
    }

}
```

Example contract used

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract Greeter {
  event _Greet(string name);

  function greet(string name) public {
    _Greet(name);
  }
}
```